# Converting a javascript library to chain methods

Tags: javascript

```
var Stuff = (function() {
    return {
        getId: function (id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        },
        attr: function (ele, attr, newVal) {
            var newVal = newVal || null;
            if (newVal) {
                ele.setAttribute(attr, newVal);
            } else {
                var attrs = ele.attributes,
                attrslen = attrs.length,
                result = ele.getAttribute(attr) || ele[attr] || null;

                if (!result) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < attrslen; i++)
                        if (attr[i].nodeName === attr) result = attr[i].nodeValue;
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

With this html:

```
<div id="foo" data-stuff="XYZ">Test Div</div>
```

The current implementation:

```
(function ($) {
    console.log(
        $.attr($.getId('foo'), 'data-stuff') // XYZ
    );
})(Stuff);
```

**How do I rewrite my library above to make it chain like the following?**

```
(function ($) {
    console.log(
        $.getId('foo').attr('data-stuff') // XYZ
    );  
})(Stuff);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building specifically from your code, you could do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/MbZ33/

```
var Stuff = (function() {
    return {
        elem:null,
        getId: function (id) {
            this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
            return this;
        },
        attr: function (attr, newVal) {
            var newVal = newVal || null;
            var ele = this.elem;
            if (newVal) {
                ele.setAttribute(attr, newVal);
            } else {
                var attrs = ele.attributes,
                attrslen = attrs.length,
                result = ele.getAttribute(attr) || ele[attr] || null;

                if (!result) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < attrslen; i++)
                        if (attr[i].nodeName === attr) result = attr[i].nodeValue;
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

This adds a `elem` property which stores the result of the `getId`. The `getId` returns `this`, which is the object referenced by `Stuff` containing all the methods. As such, you can directly call `attr` from the returned object.

I would imagine you would want to include a return value for `attr` of `this` for when the attribute is being set, so that chaining can continue.